# Javascript seperate value from array

Tags: node.js

I have this,

[{"cart_id":"5BqDu","product":[{"id":1,"qty":"11","name":"test product","pv":"100","price":"23","sub_price":253,"sub_pv":1100},{"id":2,"qty":"11","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":121,"sub_pv":null}],"shipping":{"member_id":"00000000","member_pass":"0987654321","receiver":"asasdsdasd123","full_address":"Taman ABC Lorong ccc Bagan Gajar, 11100 Pulau pINANG.","postcode":"21313213","country":"malaysia","phone_no":"321312"}},{"cart_id":"xEopa","product":[{"id":2,"qty":"1","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":11,"sub_pv":null}],"shipping":{"member_id":"09876543","member_pass":"11232312","receiver":"sdasdsadas","full_address":"adsadzcfdhg43324","postcode":"12323","country":"malaysia","phone_no":"321312"}},{"cart_id":"0WyEm","product":[{"id":2,"qty":"5","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":55,"sub_pv":null},{"id":1,"qty":"3","name":"test product","pv":"100","price":"23","sub_price":69,"sub_pv":300}],"shipping":{"member_id":"12345678","member_pass":"0987654321","receiver":"MR ABCDEF","full_address":"NO. 123, LORONG ABC, TAMAN AMAN CCC, BAGAN AJAM, 11100 KUALA LUMPUR, MALAYSIA.","postcode":"123453","country":"MALAYSIA","phone_no":"0123456789"}},{"cart_id":"ox9IK","product":[{"id":1,"qty":"2","name":"test product","pv":"100","price":"23","sub_price":46,"sub_pv":200},{"id":2,"qty":"5","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":55,"sub_pv":null}],"shipping":""},{"cart_id":"jz2j2","product":[{"id":1,"qty":"1","name":"test product","pv":"100","price":"23","sub_price":23,"sub_pv":100},{"id":2,"qty":"4","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":44,"sub_pv":null}],"shipping":""},{"cart_id":"6eE0x","product":[{"id":1,"qty":"1","name":"test product","pv":"100","price":"23","sub_price":23,"sub_pv":100}],"shipping":{"member_id":"S4567890","member_pass":"atomy123","receiver":"Siew","full_address":"56, Jalan Emas 8, Taman Bukit Beruang.","postcode":"75750","country":"Malaysia","phone_no":"0198907654"}},{"cart_id":"iRw6b","product":[{"id":2,"qty":"1","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":11,"sub_pv":null}],"shipping":{"member_id":"12345670","member_pass":"121334","receiver":"sdfsdaf","full_address":"sgdfgdfs","postcode":"12341","country":"Malaysia","phone_no":"0192321008"}},{"cart_id":"bbKf9","product":[{"id":2,"qty":"1","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":11,"sub_pv":null}],"shipping":{"member_id":"S6789212","member_pass":"12345678","receiver":"Mary","full_address":"Taman Tasik Utama","postcode":"12233","country":"Malaysia","phone_no":"0197321830"}},{"cart_id":"B1DLq","product":[{"id":2,"qty":"5","name":"test product 2","pv":"null","price":"11","sub_price":55,"sub_pv":null},{"id":1,"qty":"1","name":"test product","pv":"100","price":"23","sub_price":23,"sub_pv":100}],"shipping":{"member_id":"09876556","member_pass":"hijk","receiver":"sim","full_address":"Taman Tasik Utama","postcode":"12233","country":"Malaysia","phone_no":"0987654321"}}]

I only need **product id** from all

What can I do ?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: What is your expected output data structure? How does it look like?

Comment: my expected output data is get the  "product":[{"id":2,    2, i want it can loop and get all product id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let carts = / * the data you posted above */
let ids = [];

carts.forEach(cart => {
  const products = cart.product;
  products.forEach(product => {
    ids.push(product.id);
  });
});
```

Note that there are no check that handles a missing if property so you might want to add that.